# Trilogarithm identity violated?

Tags: special-functions

I found that the second identity in Eq. (1) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html does not hold for Mathematica's `PolyLog[3,_]` function for complex arguments with $-1 < \mathrm{Re}(z) < 0$.

Example:

```
z = -0.1;
PolyLog[3, -z] - PolyLog[3, -1/z] - (-Log[z]^3/6 - Pi^2/6 Log[z])
```

As output I obtain with Mathematica 9, 10 and 11:

```
-2.66454*10^-15 + 16.6564 I
```

I would expect that the imaginary part of the result is close to zero, i.e. the identity would hold.

Comment: From "Help" `PolyLog` has a branch cut discontinuity running from 1 to infinity.  For the values you consider, `1/z` lies on the branch cut.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! But how is it possible that for `z = -1.1` the identity is fulfilled? The value `z = -1.1` is then on the branch cut for the first term, `PolyLog[3, -z]`.

Comment: `Log` also has a branch cut on the negative real axis.  Equalities such as you cite are true in some region, but certainly on a branch cut, all bets are off.  For example, the value assigned to `Log[-1.1]` is given by convention: a value differing by `2*Pi*I` is just as valid mathematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The inversion formula does not hold in the indicated interval.

```
PolyLog[n, z] == (-1)^(n - 1) PolyLog[n, 1/z] 
- ((2 Pi I)^n/n!) BernoulliB[n, Log[-z]/(2 Pi I) + 1/2] /; !IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, 1}], z] && Element[n, Integers] && n > 0
```

See corresponding page on the [wolfram functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.08.17.0009.01)